# How to structure my npm module to use external config file if present?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am making a React component as npm module. So far I managed to use the webpack to bundle the code and everything looks good. However I want to make my module globally customizable. My approach is to use `config.json` file in the root of the project. I can't figure out how to make this in such way that:
1. If the file is not present nothing happens (I have default config in the module root folder)
2. If the file is present - use its options along with the options from the default that are not specified. The user config always needs to override the default values.

I tried conditional require, but it seems that this doesn't work

Comment: You can create a node script in a separate file and make it run through your npm command like `build`, under that node script you put a conditional statement
like ` build: node scripts/build.js`

Answer (score 1):

Write node Script and run it through NPM command like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
  },
```

Save start.js or build.js file under scripts folder with below content(this is just a reference to guide how it will work, you might have to do changes as per your requirements)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');

if (fs.existsSync('../config/webpack.config.dev.js')) {
  console.log('The file exists.');
  const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
  let compiler = webpack(config);
  compiler.run((err, stats) => {
    console.log(err, stats);
  });

}
```

You can refer the webpack node interface reference [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/)